# how to get top margin with a short line, bottom margin with full line

Tags: css

It is easier shown than described...

For a websites menu I'd like to have a "not so long line" on top and a full line below. Is it possible to do that in one class (i.e. topnav) for the  that holds the menu, or would I need more elements to do this?

[image]

Comment: more elements, like a `table`

Comment: @PedroEstrada Are you suggesting to use a `table`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to have two elements - the container element and the main element. The container element needs to be 100% wide and to have that bottom border, while the main element needs to be as wide as needed, and have the top border.

You can use `div` as a container and `ul` as the "main" element.

With help from @Brewal, here is what it looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/GTG6U/3/

```html
<div id="wrap">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>Here are</li>
        <li>many wonderful</li>
        <li>menus</li>
        <li>etc</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
}
#menu {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-top: 1px solid green;
}
#wrap {
    border-bottom: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: @Brewal Awesome, I was just about to make one!

Comment: You are smarter, you start by answering, I start by fiddling !

Comment: Haha, there's a lot of room for discussion about that. :)
Btw. see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GTG6U/1/), I made it work with non-fixed ul width so you can dynamically add/remove menu items.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd prefer having the top line be the width of the menu element, and then have an `<hr />` or similar to make the bottom edge.

That said, if you have a solid-coloured background, you could try this:

```css
#menu {
    position:relative;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
#menu:before, #menu:after {
    position:absolute;
    top:-1px;
    width:32px;
    height:3px;
    background:white;
}
#menu:before {left:0}
#menu:after {right:0}
```